# How can I use the Built-in display as the primary monitor, and a projector (via HDMI) as secondary?

Tags: display, video, mac-mini, hdmi

I have a Mac mini which has no display which I connect to it by sharing the screen to my laptop.  The Mac mini runs apps which controls my live show's backing tracks, lights and video. The video projector is connected to the mini via HDMI.

I would like the mini to still use the Built-in display as the primary, and the projector act like a second display so it can be used for the videos, but allow me to still see the Mini desktop and other apps via the screen share.  However, when the projector is connected, the Mac automatically selects it as the primary display, and Built-in Display is gone.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing - the Mac Mini does not have a built-in display. It's not a laptop. What exactly do you mean by the "built-in display" in the context of a Mac Mini?

Comment: I run my Mac Mini headless - no monitor connected, and then log into it via screen share from another computer on the network.  If I go to system preferences and look at Display, it will show me display settings for "Built-in display".  I'm assuming that's a virtual device.  If I then attach a monitor via HDMI, that monitor becomes the primary (and only) monitor.

Comment: When you say that you run it headless - do you use any hardware for that? I.e. you can purchase small dongles for DisplayPort/HDMI for simulating having a display. Is that the case here?

Comment: No, nothing is attached. when I boot.  But, maybe if I did get one of those dongles, I could make that the primary display, so that my desktop would not go to the projector?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution here is to get a "headless display dongle", which basically is a small dongle that fits into the HDMI or DisplayPort connector and simulates a display - without actually displaying anything or connecting to anything.

For examples of such a product, see for example the [fit-Headless](https://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/fit-headless/) product series or the [NewerTech display emulator](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/ADP4KHEAD/).

Comment: I ordered one, thanks for the suggestion!  I'll report back to see if I get it work the way I need it to.